# Conditional Redirection in React using useEffect not behaving as expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React application where I need to redirect users based on their authentication and verification status. I have a function called `checkRedirect` that runs inside a useEffect hook to determine if a user should be redirected or not.

```
const checkRedirect = () => {
    if (user === null && !hasNavigatedRef.current) {
        toast(' You need to Login to create a community')
        navigate("/login");
        hasNavigatedRef.current = true;
    }

    if (user.isEmailConfirmed===false) {
        toast(' You need to be Verified to create a community')
        navigate('/pr');
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    checkRedirect()
}, [user]);
```

the user in the store is set using the code below in thw app.jsx

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Fetch auth token from cookies
        const token = Cookies.get('authToken');
        const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

        if (token && user) {
            dispatch(authActions.setUser(user));
        } else if (token) {
            axios.get(`${API_URL}/me`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                },
            }).then(res => {
                dispatch(authActions.setUser(res.data));
            }).catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                dispatch(authActions.removeUser());
                Cookies.remove('authToken');
                localStorage.removeItem('user');
            });
        }
    }, [dispatch]);
```

`user` is a prop in my store, and it's `null` when the user is not logged in. `hasNavigatedRef` is a reference variable that I set to `true` once a navigation has occurred to prevent further navigations.

The expected behavior is that:

If the user is not logged in (i.e., `user` is `null`), they should be redirected to the login page.
If the user is logged in but not verified (i.e., `user.isEmailConfirmed === false`), they should be redirected to their profile page ('/pr').
However, the issue I'm facing is that even when the user is logged in, the application keeps redirecting to the login page whenever I visit this particular page.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. How can I correct this so the redirections work as expected?

Any assistance will be appreciated!

Comment: how are you getting the `user` variable? without knowing that information, chances are that `user` is null on the first render before getting set later, but since it's null on the first render the user is redirected so it never gets to the second render

Comment: this is exactly the proble. the user is gotten from the stoe, which is set y a function on the app.jsx. updated in the question above

Answer (score 0):

You should add an else statement to the first condition so that it checks for email confirmation only when the user is not null. Otherwise if the user is null, the second condition will throw an error and that's why it might keep going to the login page.

eg:

```
    const checkRedirect = () => {
    if (user === null) {
        if (!hasNavigatedRef.current) {
        toast(' You need to Login to create a community')
        navigate("/login");
        hasNavigatedRef.current = true;
    }

        else if (user.isEmailConfirmed===false) {
        toast(' You need to be Verified to create a community')
        navigate('/pr');
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    checkRedirect()
}, [user]);
```